# ImageView not getting updated accordingly in a adapter

Tags: android, view, imageview, baseadapter

I'm working with a base adapter where I want to change a ImageView accordingly to each and every action. I followed the below code to achieve it.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder1 holder1;

    char color;
    String text = "";
    String address = "";

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qq_searchlist_repeat_items,
                parent, false);

        holder1 = new ViewHolder1();
        holder1.companyName_textView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.companyName_textView);
        holder1.companyLogo_textView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.companyLogo_textView);
        holder1.companyAddress_textView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.companyAddress_textView);
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.handShakeIcon_imageView);
        holder1.favouritesIcon_imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.favouritesIcon_imageView);
        holder1.referIcon_imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.referIcon_imageView);
        holder1.sendEnquiry_imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sendEnquiry_imageView);
        holder1.icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout);
        holder1.chckbx1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbx1);

        convertView.setTag(holder1);

        if (SearchListActivity_Q2.broadcastMode) {

            Log.i("icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout is visible",
                    "icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout is visible");
            holder1.icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout
                    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder1.chckbx1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {

            holder1.icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout
                    .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder1.chckbx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        convertView.setTag(holder1);
    } else {
        holder1 = (ViewHolder1) convertView.getTag();
        holder1.chckbx1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    }

    holder1.id = position;
    holder1.chckbx1.setFocusable(false);
    Log.i("position", "position: " + position);
    search_companyName = searchresultList.get(position).getCpsName();
    search_countryName = searchresultList.get(position).getCountryName();
    holder1.chckbx1.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));

    holder1.chckbx1
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        System.out.println(position + "--- :)");

                        int cpsId2 = searchresultList.get(position)
                                .getCpsId();
                        String cpsType2 = searchresultList.get(position)
                                .getCpsType();
                        String cpsName = searchresultList.get(position)
                                .getCpsName();
                        String handShakeStatus = searchresultList.get(
                                position).getHandShakeStatus();
                        int favouriteStatus = searchresultList
                                .get(position).getFavStatus();
                        positionArray.set(position, true);
                        broadCastDetailsLists.add(new BroadCastDetailsList(
                                cpsId2, cpsType2, position, cpsName,
                                handShakeStatus, favouriteStatus));

                        if (cpsType2.equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {
                            sendEnquiry.add(new Q2_SendEnquiryList(
                                    searchresultList.get(position)
                                            .getCpsId(), searchresultList
                                            .get(position).getCpsName()));
                        }

                    } else
                        positionArray.set(position, false);

                }
            });

    try {
        String ssearch_companyName = URLDecoder.decode(search_companyName,
                "UTF-8");
        holder1.companyName_textView.setText(ssearch_companyName);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (searchresultList.get(position).getCpsName().contains(" ")) {
        String[] splitText = searchresultList.get(position).getCpsName()
                .split("\\s+");
        char a = splitText[0].charAt(0);
        char b = splitText[1].charAt(0);
        text = String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b);
        color = b;

    } else {
        text = searchresultList.get(position).getCpsName().substring(0, 1);
        color = searchresultList.get(position).getCpsName().charAt(1);
    }


    if (searchresultList.get(position).getCpsAddress().isEmpty()) {
        address = searchresultList.get(position).getCountryName();
    } else {
        if (searchresultList.get(position).getCpsAddress().length() > 1) {
            address = searchresultList.get(position).getCpsAddress() + ", "
                    + searchresultList.get(position).getCountryName();
        } else {
            address = searchresultList.get(position).getCountryName();
        }
    }

    holder1.companyAddress_textView.setText(address);

    if (searchresultList.get(position).getHandShakeStatus()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.qq_handshake);
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView.setEnabled(true);
        holder1.referIcon_imageView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (searchresultList.get(position).getHandShakeStatus()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.qq_handshake_orange);
        holder1.referIcon_imageView.setEnabled(true);
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (searchresultList.get(position).getHandShakeStatus()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.qq_handshake_blue_circle);
        holder1.referIcon_imageView.setEnabled(true);
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView.setEnabled(true);
    } else if (searchresultList.get(position).getHandShakeStatus()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.qq_handshake_blue_icon);
        holder1.referIcon_imageView.setEnabled(true);
        holder1.handShakeIcon_imageView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (searchresultList.get(position).getFavStatus() == 0) {
        holder1.favouritesIcon_imageView
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.qq_pin);
    } else {
        holder1.favouritesIcon_imageView
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.qq_pin_yellow);
    }




    SearchListActivity_Q2.handShakeIcon_imageView
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < broadCastDetailsLists.size(); i++) {
                        Log.i("cpsId", "cpsId: "
                                + broadCastDetailsLists.get(i).getCpsId());
                        Log.e("CpsType", "CpsType: "
                                + broadCastDetailsLists.get(i).getCpsType());
                        Log.e("position", "position: "
                                + broadCastDetailsLists.get(i)
                                        .getPosition());

                        if (broadCastDetailsLists.get(i).getCpsType()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {
                            companyCpsId_broadcast = companyCpsId_broadcast
                                    + "#"
                                    + broadCastDetailsLists.get(i)
                                            .getCpsId();
                        }
                    }

                    Log.i("companyCpsId_broadcast",
                            "companyCpsId_broadcast: "
                                    + companyCpsId_broadcast.replaceFirst(
                                            "#", ""));

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    handShakeCPSName = searchresultList.get(position)
                            .getCpsName();
                    handShakeStatus = searchresultList.get(position)
                            .getHandShakeStatus();
                    ConstantVariables.handShakeFromAdapter = true;

                    if (sharedpreferences.getInt("userId_sp", 0) != 0) {
                        if (sharedpreferences.getInt("profileActiveStatus",
                                0) > 0) {
                            if (sharedpreferences.getInt("organizationId",
                                    0) != 0) {

                                SearchListActivity_Q2.afterBroadCast();
                                handShakeRequest(
                                        context,
                                        broadCastDetailsLists,
                                        companyCpsId_broadcast
                                                .replaceFirst("#", ""),
                                        0,
                                        ConstantVariables.handShakeFromAdapter,
                                        searchResults_listView);

                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } else {

                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        context);
                                // Setting Dialog Title
                                // alertDialog.setTitle("Please Add Company");

                                // Setting Dialog Message
                                alertDialog
                                        .setMessage("Please add your company details");

                                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                                alertDialog
                                        .setPositiveButton(
                                                "Add",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(
                                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int which) {

                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                                                context,
                                                                Profile_Activity.class);
                                                        context.startActivity(intent);

                                                    }
                                                });

                                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                                alertDialog
                                        .setNegativeButton(
                                                "Later",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(
                                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int which) {

                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                });

                                // Showing Alert Message
                                alertDialog.show();

                            }
                        } else {
                            ConstantVariables
                                    .requestEmailVerification(context);
                        }
                    } else {
                        ConstantVariables.requestLogin(context);
                    }

                }
            });





    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder1 {
    TextView companyName_textView, companyAddress_textView,
            companyLogo_textView;
    ImageView handShakeIcon_imageView, favouritesIcon_imageView,
            referIcon_imageView, sendEnquiry_imageView;
    CheckBox chckbx1;
    int id;
    static RelativeLayout icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
}


public static void handShakeRequest(final Context c,
        final ArrayList<BroadCastDetailsList> broadCastDetailsLists,
        final String companyCpsId, final int flag,
        final boolean handShakeFromAdapter,
        final ListView searchResults_listView) {

    sharedpreferences = c.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final EditText emailId_editText;
    Button cancel_button, submit_button;
    final TextView warning_textView, verifyEmail_textView, verifyEmailDesc_textView;
    final CheckBox belowText_textView;

    final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(c,
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.handshake_dialog);

    Window window = dialog1.getWindow();

    window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog1.getWindow()
            .getAttributes();
    layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.7f;
    dialog1.getWindow()
            .addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    emailId_editText = (EditText) dialog1
            .findViewById(R.id.emailId_editText);
    verifyEmail_textView = (TextView) dialog1
            .findViewById(R.id.verifyEmail_textView);
    verifyEmailDesc_textView = (TextView) dialog1
            .findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailDesc_textView);
    cancel_button = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    submit_button = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
    warning_textView = (TextView) dialog1
            .findViewById(R.id.warning_textView);
    belowText_textView = (CheckBox) dialog1
            .findViewById(R.id.belowText_textView);

    submit_button = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.submit_button);

    cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dialog1.dismiss();
        }
    });

    submit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int reqCode = 0;
            new HandShake_WS(c, broadCastDetailsLists, companyCpsId,
                    reqCode, handShakeFromAdapter, searchResults_listView)
                    .execute();

            if (belowText_textView.isChecked()) {
                // Toast.makeText(c, "is checked",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("dontShowHandShakeDialog", 1);
                editor.commit();
                int check1 = sharedpreferences.getInt(
                        "dontShowHandShakeDialog", 0);
                Log.i("check1", "check1: " + check1);
            }
            dialog1.dismiss();
        }
    });

    if (sharedpreferences.getInt("dontShowHandShakeDialog", 0) == 1) {
        handShakeDialogStatus = true;
    } else if (sharedpreferences.getInt("dontShowHandShakeDialog", 0) == 0) {
        handShakeDialogStatus = false;
    }

    if (!handShakeDialogStatus) {
        Log.i("checkbox is not checked", "checkbox is not checked");
        dialog1.show();
    } else {
        Log.i("checkbox is checked", "checkbox is checked");
        if (flag == 0) {
            int reqCode = flag;
            new HandShake_WS(c, broadCastDetailsLists, companyCpsId,
                    reqCode, handShakeFromAdapter, searchResults_listView)
                    .execute();
        } else {
            int reqCode = 1;
            new HandShake_WS(c, broadCastDetailsLists, companyCpsId,
                    reqCode, handShakeFromAdapter, searchResults_listView)
                    .execute();
        }
    }

}

private static class HandShake_WS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    int flag;
    boolean handShakeFromAdapter;
    ListView searchResults_listView;
    Context c;
    String cpsId;
    ArrayList<BroadCastDetailsList> broadCastDetailsLists;

    public HandShake_WS(Context c,
            ArrayList<BroadCastDetailsList> broadCastDetailsLists,
            String companyCpsId, int flag, boolean handShakeFromAdapter,
            ListView searchResults_listView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cpsId = companyCpsId;
        this.c = c;
        this.flag = flag;
        this.handShakeFromAdapter = handShakeFromAdapter;

        this.searchResults_listView = searchResults_listView;
        this.broadCastDetailsLists = broadCastDetailsLists;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postData;
        postData = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject parentData = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject childData = new JSONObject();

        try {

            childData.put("userId",
                    sharedpreferences.getInt("userId_sp", 0));
            childData.put("userId",
                    sharedpreferences.getInt("organizationId", 0));
            childData.put("requestHandshakeOrgIdList", cpsId);
            childData.put("flag", flag);

            // System.out.println(childData);

            parentData.put("CPSProfileInfo", childData);

            System.out.println(parentData);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User",
        // childData.toString()));

        InputStream is = null;
        String jsonResponse = "";
        JSONObject jObj = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                    Httppost_Links.HANDSHAKE_REQUEST);

            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(new StringEntity(parentData.toString()));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            System.out.println(httpResponse);

            // HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            System.out.println(httpEntity);
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            System.out.println(is);
            System.out.println(is.toString());

            try {
                Log.e("@@@@@@@@@@", "@@@@@@@@@@@");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                jsonResponse = sb.toString();
                Log.e("JSON", "Check Json: " + jsonResponse);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error",
                        "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        JSONObject object;

        try {
            Log.i("flag", "flag: " + flag);

            if (flag == 0) {
                Log.i("111flag", "111flag: " + flag);
                final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(
                        c,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.handshake_request_sent);

                Window window = dialog1.getWindow();
                window.setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog1
                        .getWindow().getAttributes();
                layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.7f;
                dialog1.getWindow().addFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

                TextView ok_textView = (TextView) dialog1
                        .findViewById(R.id.ok_textView);
                TextView handShakeSent_textView = (TextView) dialog1
                        .findViewById(R.id.handShakeSent_textView);

                ok_textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog1.show();
            }

            object = new JSONObject(result);

            /*
             * int industryId =
             * object.getJSONObject("CPSProfileInfo").getInt( "orgId");
             * 
             * String handShakeStatus =
             * object.getJSONObject("CPSProfileInfo")
             * .getString("handShakeStatus");
             * 
             * Log.i("industryId", "industryId: " + industryId);
             */
            /*
             * ViewHolder1.icons_searchResultsPage_relLayout
             * .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             * ViewHolder1.chckbx1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             */

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < broadCastDetailsLists.size(); i++) {

            Log.i("broadCastDetailsLists.get(i).getPosition()",
                    "broadCastDetailsLists.get(i).getPosition(): "
                            + broadCastDetailsLists.get(i).getPosition());

            Log.i("searchResults_listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()",
                    "searchResults_listView.getFirstVisiblePosition(): "
                            + searchResults_listView
                                    .getFirstVisiblePosition());

            View view = searchResults_listView
                    .getChildAt(broadCastDetailsLists.get(i).getPosition()
                            - searchResults_listView
                                    .getFirstVisiblePosition());

            ImageView handShakeIcon_imageView = (ImageView) view   
                    .findViewById(R.id.handShakeIcon_imageView);     //here's my where I'm getting my null pointer exception

            handShakeIcon_imageView
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.qq_handshake_orange);
            handShakeIcon_imageView.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly for the list items which are visible in the first page while it doesn't works for the items which are in the second page and further on.
Example: If suppose there is some 200items in my list and the above code works perfectly for the items which are visible in my first page. If I scroll down and do the same action it throws null pointer exception.
[Here's my log for your reference](http://prntscr.com/88kxl4)

Can anyone please help me solving this issue...

Comment: Hey, I think you'll have to post at least the getView method implementation or the full adapter code so we can help.

Comment: Your `view` object is null, post your adapter code.